# Client и server на Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

Как соединить через интернет client и server так, чтобы server находился на другом компьютере?

Comment: Протокол какой? TCP/IP ? И кто "они" должны работать? "Интернеты"? =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, расскажите подробнее, что вы хотите сделать. А то девушка рекомендует вам начать с покупки сетевого кабеля )

Comment: Если в локалке у Вас все работает, а речь идет именно об интернет, то  серверу нужен статический IP адрес. Клиент же может иметь любой (в т.ч. из под NAT).

Comment: Это понятно, @avp. Это каждому известно.

Answer (score 2):

Для клиент-сервера попробуйте посмотреть в сторону сокетов (библиотека Delphi - dclsock70.bpl, если не ошибаюсь. Это проще всего. Или через стандартный виндовый winsock) или Synapse